# How to display the detail of an array's index in a new view?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have table view which is populated from an array grabbed from a url. I set the title of each row with a few characters from the string object of array and when the cell is clicked a new view is pushed. In this new view i have a `UILabel`. At this point what i want is, to set the title of this lable with the full string of that index..

Here is my code:

```
 NSDictionary *object=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"savedMessage"];
    NSArray *array= [object valueForKey:@"message"];


    cell.textLabel.text= [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and by the following code i push new view:

```
 messageDetail *detailViewController = [[messageDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"messageDetail" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     detailViewController.title=@"Message Detail";

    [detailViewController release];
```

What i want is, how can display any result(detail) of the array at its own index?
(for example, when i clicked the 5. row i want my detailViewController's label be set as the 5. object of array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a function in messageDetail.m called like so:

```
- (void)updateLabelWith:(NSString *)labelString{
    label.text = labelString;}
```

And then you call it in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in tableViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *labelString = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // data is an NSArray of Strings
    [detailViewController updateLabelWith:labelString];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];}
```

Comment: thanks man, i had solve in a different way, 
i saved indexPath.row to NSUserDefaults and retrieved it in the other class as an array again..